# How to best access class specific methods when its contained in a type that it inherits?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

Lets say i have a custom control class that inherits the "Control" class in winforms. I spawn these controls in runtime and pile them into the controls collection of a panel.

Now I want to iterate through these custom controls and execute a sub specific to its class. At first thought, I wanted to iterate through the controls collection of the panel but this is no good since the control type doesn't have the sub I'm looking for.

Obviously, I could double store them in a duplicate list with the appropriate class.. The question is though, is there a better way to do this? Like in various scripting languages I've had the option to cast the type on spot or cast the entire collection to a cast reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all the `Control`s in your `Panel`.  Use the [`TryCast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx) operator to determine if any are instances of your custom control and if so call your method.

Something like this:

```
For Each c In panel.Controls
    Dim control As YourCustomControl = TryCast(c, YourCustomControl)
    If Not control Is Nothing Then
        control.YourMethod
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It works, all though, I think I'll stick to the duplicate list.